# C# project level date format?

Tags: c#, winforms, locale, date-format

So I had a project which I sent to a friend who uses US as his locale. Since he sent me back the project I cannot reconcile the locale differences!

In design mode, I look at a date picker properties for instance, and it shows "13/05/2016 14:55" for the value, "31/12/9998" for max etc. How it should be.

Once I run the project though, `DateTime.Now` returns "05/13/2016 14:55" AND `DatePicker.Value` also returns "05/13/2016 14:55"!

How can I get my project back to the proper project locale?!?!

Comment: What type of project is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In .NET, the locale will default to your computer's current locale, as reported by the OS. Most likely, your friend is manually setting the locale somewhere in the code. The designer instantiates the view by itself, which is why the designer appears to use your current locale. You should search through the source code to locate where the locale is being set. You can override this setting yourself, though I would not recommend it. Instead, I would simply remove it. I think it is best to allow .NET to pull the OS locale in most cases.

Search for references to `CurrentCulture` `CurrentUICulture` and `CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture` to see if you can find the code altering the locale.

Comment: I was just going to say to do this, nicely done. The `Designer` views still execute the `.cs` code to draw the controls - and changes to the culture would cause this issue.

Comment: What do you know, buried in the Load method he was setting the Culture to "en". That's not even a culture. Thanks for saving me a few hours!